# how do I get the link name from Excel or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I'd like to have my spreadsheet behave differently depending on how I call it.

From file explorer I can double click on either "*UHF-test.xlsm*" or its shortcut, "*VHF-test.lnk*". From VBA or an Excel formula, how do I determine which one was used?

If I can't determine the link name, is there another way to pass information in the command line, something like this BAT file

```
 start "\B" EXCEL \\qcy-win10-it-2\TDS-repository\TDS-UAXTED.xlsm -VHF
```

Comment: If the file and the shortcut(s) are in different folders you could use their paths to determine which is which - 

`Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    debug.print Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
End Sub`

Comment: I don’t think I understand fully. Please explain why you want to know which of them it uses. Or do you just want to create a code, that opens the one you want it to?

Comment: To answer, "why?", let me explain: I have **one spreadsheet** with macros I maintain that is able to handle different product types and parameters. When I have to replicate the spreadsheet with only slightly different parameters for differing products and frequency bands, my job becomes really difficult. If through initialization I can identify version and parameters, my job becomes more manageable. Not only that but I don't want to expose my users to the "*man behind the curtain*", I want their experience to be seamless..

Answer (score 0):

The BAT file solution works fairly well, it's a very small file where I can embed some options for running macros. A small downside is that the Excel PATH is not normally in the system execution PATH and needs to be added.

The goal is toI write and maintain **one only** macro-enabled spreadsheet stored in a network location but with the ability to allow multiple users to use it with different products and parameters without being prompted by a macro on startup.

I still prefer determining the shortcut name if someone has that solution.

Comment: What about using VBA. Environ("username") instead?

Comment: I already use that **all the time**, the products and parameters are not user dependent, it's product/frequency/power-level dependent. That's why I want to pass in that type of information surreptitiously, through the name.